# How to set the flashlight/screen light turn on for different time periods based on user requirement?

Tags: android

Am developing an flashlight application in which I want to give option to set the timer for the flashlight to the user.
This is the code for the flash to be on:
How I could implement it for 2 minutes, 3 minutes etc?

```
camera = Camera.open();
parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread.sleep(user decided period);

Answer (score 0):

Launching new thread and sleeping it is very resource-consuming. `Handler` method `postDelayed` is recommended for such usage.